# WebView displaying blank

Tags: android, webview, android-8.1-oreo

I'm having problems displaying locally-generated HTML content in a WebView under Oreo.  The code in question has worked perfectly on everything up until Oreo, but on Oreo I only get an empty white window.

My layout is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:minHeight="400dp"
    android:minWidth="400dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The class that uses this derives from DialogFragment.  The code to setup the content is as follows:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Resources resources = getResources();

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_tablet, container, false);
    webView = v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new LinkClickLauncher(getActivity(), objectFactory));

    String content = "";
    String title = "";

    //code that assembles the content omitted.
    //(I've verified the HTML is valid)

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/leafTemplate.html",
                                content,
                                "text/html",
                                "utf-8",
                                null);

    Dialog dialog = getDialog();

    dialog.setTitle(title);

    dialogUtils.adjustTitleColors(dialog, R.color.theme_navy, R.color.theme_navy);

    return v;
}
```

The `content` I'm feeding to `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL` is a simple HTML string - I'm not trying to access anything off the Internet.

Things I've tried without any success:

Adding:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
```

Changing the baseUrl argument of loadDataWithBaseURL to `"about:blank"` and `null`.

Replacing my HTML generation with a simple:

```
content = "<html><body><p>Hello World!</p></body></html>";
```

In all cases, I just get a white screen.

As I said, this has been working just fine up to and including Nougat, but is now failing on Oreo.

Suggestions?

Comment: I removed my answer, as it is not necessary to be here and it was not helpful to you